# Modismo para "Round hole square peg problem"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, solicitud-de-término, solicitud-de-modismo

La explicación más visual para el modismo "Round hole square peg problem" es posiblemente ese juguete que tienen los niños pequeños que consiste en bloques de madera de distintas formas y colores (un cuadrado, una estrella, un cilindro o círculo, etc.) que hay que poner en una caja, bien en el agujero de su correspondiente forma o a través de un agujero.

El modismo hace referencia a intentar meter una de las piezas por el agujero que no es. La figura por supuesto no cabe, por más que lo forcemos. La expresión se usa en inglés para decir "esto no pertenece aquí" (usada tanto para personas como para "cosas", incluidas soluciones a problemas).

> "Square peg in a round hole" is an idiomatic expression which describes the unusual individualist who could not fit into a niche of his or her society
>
> Fuente: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole)

Con el significado de "estás forzando esa solución" o "combinando cosas que no encajan juntas":

> [...] to continue with the old diplomatic approach would be like hammering square pegs into round holes.
>
> (misma fuente)

¿Existe algún modismo en español que signifique algo parecido tipo, "no vas a poder hacer funcionar esa solución ni a martillazos; eso no encaja"?

[image]

Comment: Se me ocurre "esto no pega ni con cola", pero creo que usa la acepción 10 de ["pegar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SKdzxQw) (armonizar una cosa con otra). No sé si podría usarse en el ámbito que comentas. Tal vez "sentirse como pez fuera del agua", por aquello de no encajar en un grupo, apelando a los sentimientos de la persona. Es una pregunta interesante, a ver si se me ocurre algo mejor...

Comment: En Argentina es común la expresión _"Ser (o sentirse) sapo de otro pozo"_ cuando alguien no encaja, o siente que no encaja, en un medio.

Comment: Muchas veces esta frase se usa para *misfit*, alguien que *nunca* se va a sentir como alguien de la misma tribu que la gente de alrededor.  Pero también conozco esta expresión en inglés en este contexto: Hay un niño con ADHD.  La maestra no sabe manejarlo bien, y trata de romperle el espíritu.  Trata de quitar las esquinas para que quepa la pieza cuadrada en un agujero redondo.  Es decir, quieren que todos tomen la forma redonda, y que ya no haya variedad humana.

Comment: @aparente001 No digo que eso no pase, pero no creo que sea la situación en la que aplicar o en la que se aplica el modismo. Sería admitir que estás tratando de _deformar_ a un niño para que entre dentro de uno de los patrones establecidos (y nadie lo va admitir). Curiosamente, lo que sí oigo mucho es aquello de "si juzgas a un pez por su capacidad de trepar árboles, se va a sentir un inútil por el resto de su vida", pero paradójica o hipócritamente, no veo que sea eso lo que se aplique tampoco. No creo que se atienda del todo bien a las distintas formas de aprender que tenemos unos y otros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De momento lo más parecido que se me ocurre es:

> **[entrar algo con calzador](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6sm5cbG)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Ser dificultoso o estar forzado.

Esta expresión también se puede escribir como "intentar meter algo con calzador", que sería intentar forzar algo en un sitio que no le corresponde.

No estoy seguro de que respete exactamente el sentido original de la expresión inglesa, pero si no es así debe de andar cerca. La expresión española implica que, en un momento dado, la solución propuesta (metida con calzador) podría llegar a funcionar, pero no sin dificultad previa y habiendo otras opciones menos costosas.

Comment: Quizá sea dificil usarlo para personas ("no encajo en la cultura de esa empresa ni con calzador") pero es genial para el sentido más general de una solución. Al igual que en el original "no entra ni auqnue lo fuerces".

Answer (score 3):

Con el sentido de "estar forzando la solución" tenemos la frase

["Cuando la única herramienta que tienes es un martillo, todo problema comienza a parecerse a un clavo"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martillo_de_oro)

queriendo decir que aunque la solución no se adapte de igual manera se va a forzar su aplicación al problema.

Con el sentido de que el problema es muy difícil de resolver y que nada de lo que tenemos a la mano lo puede solucionar, hay varias frase coloquiales con similar significado:

- Más difícil que matar un burro a pellizcos
- como encontrar una aguja en un pajar.
- buscarle tres patas al gato (este nunca me ha parecido lógico)
- Pedirle peras al olmo (esa solución es para otro problema)

y por ultimo con el sentido de una persona que se siente fuera de su ambiente tenemos:

- como mosco en la sopa (o la leche)
- como gallina en corral ajeno

Comment: Genial!! La versión inglesa la he oído un montón, y nunca pensé en relacionarla con la otra (cuando solo quieres usar un _square peg_ lo fuerzas incluso en un _round hole_). Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

En un registro más culto, también existe el término [*lecho de Procusto*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procusto) y el adjetivo *procústeo*.

Procusto era un personaje mitológico que exigía un ajuste exacto de los [huéspedes](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=hu%E9sped) a la cama que les ofrecía.

> Si la víctima era alta y su cuerpo era más largo que la cama, procedía
>   a serrar las partes del cuerpo que sobresalían: los pies y las manos o
>   la cabeza. Si, por el contrario, era de menor longitud que la cama, lo
>   descoyuntaba a martillazos hasta estirarlo (de aquí viene su nombre).

Puede usarse en el sentido de hacer encajar algo a la fuerza:

> Un **lecho de Procusto**, también llamado **cama de Procusto**, es un estándar
>   arbitrario para el que se fuerza una conformidad exacta. Se aplica
>   también a aquella [falacia seudocientífica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seudociencia) en la que se tratan de
>   deformar los datos de la realidad para que se adapten a la hipótesis
>   previa.

En ergonomía, se usa el adjetivo *procústeo* si son las personas las que se deben adaptar a la fuerza a los objetos y no al contrario (como sería deseable).

> En general se denomina **procústeo** a aquello opuesto a lo [ergonómico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergon%C3%B3mico) , es
>   decir, que parte de la idea de que es la persona quien debe adaptarse
>   a los objetos y no al revés.

Creo que estos términos pueden ser de utilidad en ciertos contextos.

Answer (score 2):

Aclaración del modismo (espero que esto ayude a llegar a una buena traducción):

Conozco dos maneras de usar esta frase.  Una describe la falta de concordancia, y la otra observa lo inútil de forzar la pieza a entrar en el hoyo incorrecto. Una imagen que ilustra la segunda:

[image: martillo, pieza cuadrada, hoyo redondo]

La imagen aparece en un [artículo](http://blog.eisgroup.com/disruptionandinsurance) que dice

> Are insurers force-fitting disruption on old operating models and systems? [...] Without a solid foundation, the whole exercise of customer-centered transformation will be a frustrating practice of banging square pegs into round holes.

Hay otros artículos que podría citar pero me gustó ese por la imagen.

Para este uso del modismo, propongo:

**quitar las esquinas para que quepa la pieza cuadrada en un agujero redondo**

Yo utilizo este modismo en la siguiente situación:

> Hay un niño con ADHD. La maestra no sabe manejarlo bien, y trata de romperle el espíritu. Trata de quitar las esquinas para que quepa la pieza cuadrada en un agujero redondo. Es decir, quieren que todos tomen la forma redonda, como si no hubiera variedad neurológica.